# Get item from Serena Dimensions without knowing Item Specification

Tags: serena

I want to download a file from serena dimensions with script. I found from the manual that the command is **FI**

I am writing it like this

```
FI "" /USER_FILENAME="C:\path_to_my_file" /NOEXPAND /OVERWRITE
```

And i got this error:
**PCM0005518E Error: Item not uniquely identified**

Is there any way that with just the filename i can fetch the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
FI /ROOT_PROJECT="PROD_NAME:PROJECT_NAME" /FILENAME="DIMENSION_PORJECT/PATH/FILENAME" - /USER_FILENAME="C:\path_local\set_filename.ext" /NOEXPAND /OVERWRITE
```

What is being done here is using ROOT_PROJECT we are limiting the search area to product and project. Then we are providing the full path of file in dimensions using the /FILENAME and then we are providing the local copy path in the /USER_FILENAME. This is where the file from the dimensions will be copied to.

In scenario your file in dimension has global scope or is in $GENRIC:$GLOBAL scope then you can get away by only the /FILENAME.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!Just one more thing. I need to add also the SCWS command at the top of my script because i have different default project and it doesn't let me get the file i want. So with SCWS i switch the projects and then i run your FI command to do the job. If you want you can update the answer by adding this first --->

SCWS "PROD_NAME:PROJECT_NAME" /NOCHECK /DIRECTORY="C:\DirName" /USER_BRANCH="." /CHANGE="." /PART="." /LIBRARY_CACHE_AREA="." /NODEFAULT