# Serena Command line, get item-spec

Tags: command-line-interface, serena

I have a utility I use to help verify releases.

One of the things it does is grab a number of files from Serena based on folder/filename to compare to files from other sources.

Most files can be retrieved like this:
FI "F17C:F17AR ARR CASENO EDITS CFM.A-DAT" /FILENAME=FHA_Connection\clas\html\f17ar-arr-caseno-edits.cfm /USER_FILENAME=C:\java\projects\release-checker\check\20210704-outputs\referenced-modules\serena\clas\html\f17ar-arr-caseno-edits.cfm /OVERWRITE /NOMETADATA /EOL=WINDOWS

Where I have problems is that some files have "-nnnnnn" just prior to the .A-DAT.

I don't know how to predict what that string of numeral will be, so I can't match the item spec on those files and get an error that the file exists but the spec is wrong.

Omitting the "F17AR ARR CASENO EDITS CFM.A-DAT" portion does not work

Is there a way to use wildcards in the item id, or to grab the file knowing only the full filename and the product id?

If the Serena documentation explains this; I'm not grasping it. :(

Comment: I have discovered that I can get most files by just specifying the product (F17C:) -- it was the omission of the colon that was messing me up when I had tried that originally.  Some still give me a "not in this project" message when they clearly are, so I'm chasing that.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984254/get-item-from-serena-dimensions-without-knowing-item-specification